# Why is this code from Bjarne's "Tour of C++" valid?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

If we pass an array to the function, we iterate through it until "p" is a nullptr. But this should never happen because the address after the last element that has value 0 in the array is not a nullptr(doesn't have value zero). How is this possible?

```
int count_x(char* p, char x)
// count the number of occurrences of x in p[]
// p is assumed to point to a zero-ter minated array of char (or to nothing)
{
  int count = 0;
  while (p) {
    if (*p==x)
      ++count;
    ++p;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: Careful with those crazy non-ASCII asterisks.

Comment: He probably copied the code from an ebook. I have fixed the asterisks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That function is not valid. Your version of the book contains an error.  The correct version tests `*p` in the `while` condition.

```
int count_x(char* p, char x)
    // count the number of occurrences of x in p[]
    // p is assumed to point to a zero-terminated array of char (or to nothing)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (*p) {
//         ^----------------- You omitted this asterisk.
        if (*p==x)
            ++count;
        ++p;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Update: the code apparently changed a little bit between printings, and [the errata for the first printing](http://www.stroustrup.com/Tour_printing2.html) mentions an error related to this function. Hat tip to @BenVoigt.

Comment: No, I didn't copy it wrong. Here is a screenshot from the book: http://postimg.org/image/5quxkcnhf/

Comment: Then you got a lousy ebook version. Go to the [paperback edition on amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Tour-In-Depth-Series-Bjarne-Stroustrup/dp/0321958314), click on the cover to "Look Inside”, and type “occurrences” in the search box. You'll see that the print version (on page 12) matches my answer.

Comment: @rob: The errata lists that page as having known bad code in the first printing, fixed in the second.

Comment: @J.M: As long as you use it together with the author's errata list, yes.

Comment: You should try to get an ebook of the third printing. The copyright page of the Kindle edition, for example, say it's the third printing (January 2015).

Answer (score 3):

The code is wrong.

The `while` condition needs to be

```
while(*p)
```

instead of

```
while(p)
```

EDIT: Found it in the errata also - http://www.stroustrup.com/Tour_printing2.html

> pp 11-12: The code for count_if() is wrong (doesn't do what it claims
>   to), but the points made about the language are correct.

Comment: I think you mean the `while` condition, not the `if` condition.

Comment: No, the code in the book is as I presented it. Look here: http://postimg.org/image/5quxkcnhf/